# Applet Code runing well in eclipse environement but not in the browser

Tags: java, applet, javax.imageio

i'm stucked on this point since 3 days and i'm out of idea.
If someone could help, my week will start really well !

I'm writing a java applet.

- Under eclipse environement it works well.
- I build the jar (with all the dependencies aggregated) and launch it on a browser (chrome, firefox, ie ...). The code below does not work anymore because it returns an empty list:

Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");

It seems that the Image Readers that claim to be able to decode the DICOM format are available under eclipse environement but not under browser environement ...
I don't think it's a security exception as i have no such error (I have no exception, problem is the returned list is empty).

Thanks in advance for any clue ...

Comment: Hey, man! Are you still interested in a solution? _Do you have any messages in Java Console?_

Comment: Hi, I've found the solution. A spi image reader was not found into the manifest. It was because the dependencies jar files were aggregated into my jar, leading the manifest to be overriden. Now I don't aggregate my jar anymore so it's ok !

Comment: You should place here the answer to your own question. To help other people understand that your problem is solved; and how to solve it, if others also get the same problem. Here we help each other, not only ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. A spi image reader was not found into the manifest. It was because the dependencies jar files were aggregated into my jar, leading my manifest to be overriden by another. Now I don't aggregate my jar anymore and it's ok, my manifest stay safe and the spi image reader is found.